# FFmpeg command runs In Terminal, but not in script with TMux

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, script, tmux

The first time I ran the FFmpeg command I got error:

> “Output file #0 does not contain any stream”

…but I could see the Tux session and connect to it.

Then added the full path to the FFmpeg executable and reduced the complexity of the FFmpeg command, but now nothing happens, not even a tmux session is created.

```
sh rec.sh
```

And here are the contents of `rec.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d /usr/bin/ffmpeg -f pulse -i 0 -acodec libmpelame out.mp3
```

Comment: Why are you invoicing TMux in the shell script?

Comment: FFmpeg command runs for hours and can do other things while it runs. Can also stop the FFmpeg command via SSH from another computer.

Comment: Fair enough. Posted an answer. TL;DR… Try adding the `-nostdin` to the FFmpeg command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when you run an FFmpeg in a Bash script the `-nostdin` option should be used. So the command in your shell script would change to this:

```
tmux new-session -d /usr/bin/ffmpeg -nostdin -f pulse -i 0 -acodec libmp3lame out.mp3
```

Another similar way to deal with this would be to append `< /dev/null` to the command like this:

```
tmux new-session -d /usr/bin/ffmpeg -f pulse -i 0 -acodec libmp3lame out.mp3 < /dev/null
```

Try either of them and use what works as explained the [FFmpeg documentation for `-stdin`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html); bold emphasis is mine:

> Enable interaction on standard input. On by default unless standard input is used as an input. To explicitly disable interaction you need to specify `-nostdin`.
>
> Disabling interaction on standard input is useful, for example, if ffmpeg is in the background process group. **Roughly the same result can be achieved with `ffmpeg ... < /dev/null` but it requires a shell.**

Comment: Well, you are running the script like this: `sh rec.sh` but the script itself has `#!/bin/bash`. So you can run the script like this from the path: `./rec.sh`

Comment: The first option I tried before, nothing happens (no errors), when running "tmux ls" I get: "no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default". The second option gives error: ": No such file.sh: cannot open /dev/null". This is running on latest RPi OS image. The script is on the Desktop folder and has execute permissions.

Comment: Also tried running it like that: "./rec.sh" (with both options separately), but got error: "~bash: ./rec.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such fiile or directory" each time.

Comment: That Bash error means the script was saved with  weird text encoding. That `^M` is the big clue. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14219160/117259) for more details. That is fairly major so solve that first and then run the script as `./rec.sh`. And another idea: Perhaps TMux doesn’t even start with that command because you are not indicating the full path for the binary. So maybe this: `/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d /usr/bin/ffmpeg -nostdin -f pulse -i 0 -acodec libmp3lame out.mp3`

Comment: Happy this worked! First, that `#!/bin/bash` is useless if it worked with `sh`. So either delete that line or change it to `#!/bin/sh`. Or check where Bash is located on that system by running `which bash`. If it doesn’t work with `-nostdin` it means perhaps an old version of FFmpeg is on that system? The `< /dev/null` is another way of disabling standard input interaction. Just edited the answer to explain that it is an FFmpeg specific thing; not a general shell scripting thing.

Comment: Deleted the script and created a new one with your line above. Ran the script with "./rec.sh" and nothing happened, but with "< /dev/null" it ran fine. What can be concluded about my environment? Should I always use "< /dev/null" to run any and all commands, or just once in the script file?

Comment: Yes, FFmpeg is an old version that comes as default (v4.1.6-1). The location for bash is /usr/bin/bash. The "< /dev/null" worked with both "./rec.sh" and "sh rec.sh". Removed the first line and the script still worked.

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks!